# Kernel Module to Ethernet Packet Echo

Tags: linux, networking, module, kernel, ethernet

I develop a linux kernel module to re-transmit some ethernet packet (do the echo). THe packet arrives, i check the ethernet destination address, and if it is for me, i re-transmit. If not i do nothing.

I used dev_pack_eth to define my protocol handler to recieve all ethernet packet (EHT_P_ALL) and dev_queue_xmit to transmit the skb buff received.

It works, the echo is functional but...

Sometimes, very often. the kernel crashs and i don't know why.

When i re-transmit the packet, i return NET_RX_Sucess.

When i don't re-transmit i use kfree_skb to free the skb buff received and return NET_RX_DROP.

I think the problem my be on this issues. Can you help me?

If needed i could post the kernel module code.

Best Regards!

------------Edit:Code added--------

```
#include <linux/module.h>   /* Needed by all modules */
#include <linux/kernel.h>   /* Needed for KERN_INFO */
#include <linux/init.h>     /* Needed for the macros */
#include <linux/skbuff.h>
#include <linux/if_ether.h>
#include <linux/netdevice.h>
#include <linux/netfilter.h>
#include <linux/netfilter_ipv4.h>
#include <linux/netfilter_bridge.h>
#include <asm-generic/types.h>


/*Buscar as interfaces de rede*/
struct net_device *dev_eth0;
struct net_device *dev_eth1;
int contador;

static struct packet_type hook; /* Initialisation routine */

void handler_add_config (void);
void handler_remove(void);
void print_mac_hdr(struct ethhdr *eth);

static int hook_func( struct sk_buff *skb)
{

        struct ethhdr *eth;    
        struct ethhdr aux;

        eth= eth_hdr(skb)
        print_mac_hdr(eth);


       /*If destination isn't the same that dev_addr, the packet is not for me: do nothing*/
        if(memcmp(eth->h_dest,skb->dev->dev_addr,ETH_ALEN)!=0)
            {
            printk("NÃ£o sÃ£o iguais!!!\n");
            }
        else
            {
        /*Swap addr*/
            memcpy(&(aux.h_dest),eth->h_dest,ETH_ALEN);
            memcpy(eth->h_dest,eth->h_source,ETH_ALEN);
            memcpy(eth->h_source,&(aux.h_dest),ETH_ALEN);
     /*Re build ther hearders*/
            skb->data = (unsigned char *)skb->mac_header;
            skb->len += ETH_HLEN;

            skb->pkt_type = PACKET_OUTGOING;

                  /*Send*/
                if(dev_queue_xmit(skb)!= NET_XMIT_SUCCESS)
                 {
                      printk("Erro na transmissÃ£o\n");
                 }
                else
                 {
                      printk("Trama retransmitida com sucesso\n");
                      return NET_RX_SUCCESS;
                 }

            }



    kfree_skb(skb);
    return NET_RX_DROP;
}

/*Print eth  headers*/
void print_mac_hdr(struct ethhdr *eth)
{
    printk("Destino: %02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x \n",eth->h_dest[0],eth->h_dest[1],eth->h_dest[2],eth->h_dest[3],eth->h_dest[4],eth->h_dest[5]);
    printk("Origem: %02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x\n",eth->h_source[0],eth->h_source[1],eth->h_source[2],eth->h_source[3],eth->h_source[4],eth->h_source[5]);
    printk("Proto: 0x%04x\n",ntohs(eth->h_proto));

}

/*Configure Protocol Handler*/

void handler_add_config (void)
{
        hook.type = htons(ETH_P_ALL);
        hook.func = (void *)hook_func;
        hook.dev = NULL;
        dev_add_pack(&hook);
        printk("Handler Protocol adicionado!!!!\n");

}
/*Unregist protocol handler*/
void handler_remove(void)
{
    dev_remove_pack(&hook);
    printk("Handler Protocol removido!!!!\n");
    synchronize_net();/*Sincronizar a rede!*/
}

/*Init module and protocol handler*/
static int __init hook_init(void)
{

    printk("Hello:I'm the hook module!!!!\n");
    contador =0;
    dev_eth0=dev_get_by_name(&init_net,"eth0");
    dev_eth1=dev_get_by_name(&init_net,"eth1");
    handler_add_config();
    return 0;
}


/*Remove module and protocol handler*/
static void __exit hook_exit(void)
{

    printk("Hook module says Goodbye!!!!!\n");
    handler_remove();

}

module_init(hook_init);
module_exit(hook_exit);
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Comment: Please post the code. Debugging code is hard, debugging without code impossible.

Comment: Can you also add the kernel error output?

Comment: I try to  check the last kernel's message at /var/log but don't say nothing (or at least i don't found it). Tomorrow i will try to look better because  the pc where i was programming isn't with me now. If possible i will try to add. Thank you.

Comment: I don't find the error message.

Comment: Try running without a graphical interface (i.e. without X). You should see the error message on the console when it occurs. Alternatively, look into setting up a serial console.

Comment: Is possible that if the interface goes down...the kernell crashes? Because the module continues re-direct packet to an interface that is disable.

Comment: If the interface is down I wouldn't expect packets to keep coming in. It's possible that there's a race condition in there, but that'd mean the crash is very rare and you said it happened very often.

Comment: I don't know what to do. The kernel didn't sent an error message.

Answer (score 0):

i think when u are returning **return NET_RX_DROP;** it causes problem because there are basically return types in hooks are ...

```
Return Code          Meaning
  NF_DROP        Discard the packet.
  NF_ACCEPT      Keep the packet.
  NF_STOLEN      Forget about the packet.
  NF_QUEUE       Queue packet for userspace.
  NF_REPEAT      Call this hook function again.
```

& u are returning NET_RX_DROP so try to use **NF_DROP**.

Answer (score 0):

Look at af_x25.c in net/x25 for a sample implementation of the same where they return 0 even on a drop. BTW didn't understand why are you incrementing skb->len when all you are doing is swapping the mac addresses ? I.e why the need to rebuild hdrs in that sense? Am i missing something here?

Comment: Ok to answer my own question, it's needed since the ETH HDR is stripped off in eth_type_trans() that would be invoked by the NIC device driver in it's Rx routine.

Answer (score -2):

You are probably crashing because you are freeing the slngle copy of sk_buff by calling     kfree_skb(skb);